# Loop with delay or completion in objective c

Tags: ios, loops, completionhandler

I have an app wherein I need to loop through and load stored data in order to generate information to save to PDF file, pages. I created a loop, but it runs too fast, so to speak. The saved pages cannot load fast enough, so the resulting data is incomplete. I think I need to create a for loop with delay or completion handler. Something like:

```
for (int i = 0, i < numberOfPages, doTaskWithCompletion:i++) {
    arrayOfPages = [self loadDataAtIndex:i withCompletionHandler:handler];
    [self writeDataToFile:arrayOfPages];
}
```

Not even sure how to write that pseudo-code, but basically I only want to jump to the next iteration after a completion handler has fired for the task of loading the data.

Note: Source data comes from core data, saved as PDF file. The data is pages and views for page. Each page can have 1 or unlimited views. Each view might have data too, like an image. What happens currently is that the number of pages written is correct, but the page's views that are rendered to PDF are identical, because they all read the same data, as the pages are not loaded before the PDF is written.

Comment: Where is the stored data?  Is it in a directory, core data, etc?  How many data points do you expect?  10 or 10,000?

Comment: @jb_OH Source data comes from core data, saved as PDF data file. The data is pages and views for page. Each page can have 1 - unlimited views. Each view might have data too, like an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may approach the problem as follows:

First define a generic completion block type. Note, param *result* can be anything. If it's an `NSError` this signals a failure, otherwise success.

```
typedef void (^completion_t)(id result);
```

Define a block type for your asynchronous task. Your task takes an index as input, and - since it is asynchronous, it takes a completion block as last parameter:

```
typedef void (^unary_async_t)(int index, completion_t completion);
```

Your task block object can be *defined* as follows:

```
unary_async_t task = ^(int index, completion_t completion) {
    [self loadDataAtIndex:index withCompletion:^(id result){
        if (![result isKindOfClass:[NSError class]]) {
            [self writeDataToFile:result];
            result = @"OK";
        }
        if (completion) {
            completion(result);
        }
    }];
};
```

Note: your `loadDataAtIndex:withCompletion:` is asynchronous, and thus, it takes a completion block as last parameter. The completion block's parameter *result* is the result of the asynchronous task, namely the "array of pages" - or an `NSError` object if that fails.

In this completion block, you safe your result (the pages) to disk, invoking `writeDataToFile:`. (We assuming this won't fail).  If that is all finished, *task* invokes the provided completion block *completion* (if not nil) passing the result of the whole operation, which  is @"OK" in case of success, and an `NSError` in case of failure.

Now, the more interesting part: how to make this in a loop, where numerous _task_s will be executed sequentially, one after the other:

We define two helper methods - or functions:

What we finally need is a function with this signature:

```
void apply_each_with_range(int lowerBound, int upperBound, 
                           unary_async_t task, completion_t completion);
```

This is the function which shall invoke *task* N times, passing it parameter *index* in the range from *lowerBound* (including) to *upperBound* (not including), where *N* equals *upperBound* - *lowerBound* and *index* starts with *lowerBound*.

It's an asynchronous function, and thus, takes a completion block as last parameter. Do I repeat myself? Well, you should recognize the pattern! ;)

Here is the implementation:

```
void apply_each_with_range(int lowerBound, int upperBound, 
                           unary_async_t task, completion_t completion)
{
    do_apply(lowerBound, upperBound, task, completion);
}
```

And the other helper - which is finally performing some sort of "**for_each index in range[upperBound, lowerBound]  *sequentially* invoke *task* with parameter *index***":

```
static void do_apply(int index, int upperBound, 
                     unary_async_t task, completion_t completion)
{
    if (index >= upperBound) {
        if (completion)
            completion(@"OK");
        return;
    }
    task(index, ^(id result) {
        if (![result isKindOfClass:[NSError class]]) {
            do_apply(index + 1, upperBound, task, completion);
        }
        else {
            // error occurred: stop iterating and signal error
            if (completion) {
                completion(result);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

The function `do_apply` first checks whether the index is out of range. If, then it is finished and calls the completion handler with an @"OK".
Otherwise, it invokes *task* with argument *index* and provides a completion handler which gets invoked when *task* finished, which itself passes the result of the task. If that was successful, `do_apply` will invoke itself with argument index incremented by one. This may look like a "recursion" - but it is not. `do_apply` already returned, when it invokes itself.

If *task* returned and error, `do_apply` stops, "returning" the error from *task* in its completion handler (which is finally provided by the call-site).

Now, you just need to put these pieces together in your project - which should be fairly easy.

Answer (score 0):

You can test to see if the data is saved and set a flag to see whether or not the data is saved. Then put an if statement like if the flag is set to yes then run the for loop. You can do something like that for all of your data to make sure all data is stored. Good luck!! Hope this helps!!